# How do I publish a website made with Symfony?

Tags: symfony, publish, symfony4

I have made a website with Symfony. It works fine on my local server but when I try to publish it on my hosting space (OVH), I've got an "Index of" error.

[Home page - error "Index of"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wy50Y.png)

I know people who use Symfony the same way I did and their websites work.
So what could be the problem ?

Thank you.

Comment: How is your webserver configured? (directory listing, Defaultpage ....)

Answer (score 1):

Your webserver seems be not configured properly.

You should follow [this](https://symfony.com/doc/current/setup/web_server_configuration.html) piece of doc and ask here if you have any problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can find a detailed process about how to deploy Symfony applications here:

https://symfony.com/doc/current/deployment.html

Also, you can find here (in Spanish, but you can easily translate) how to config Symfony 2 Applications, it's easier to adapt to Symfony 4.

https://symfony.es/documentacion/como-configurar-bien-apache-para-las-aplicaciones-symfony2/